# Implementing a balanced binary search tree?

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have implemented a binary search tree and I want to add more functionality in its insertion function to make it a self-balancing tree.  I am coding in C#.

Can anybody please suggest me good tutorials or links on this?  I did some searches and found some links, but none of them were descriptive enough.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of data are you storing in the tree, and why?

Comment: I would suggest looking up a Red Black Tree.

Comment: I'd look for AVL trees. AFAIK they are easier to implement than red-black trees.

Comment: I would suggest looking at `System.Collections.Generic.SortedList<T>`

Comment: Well, guys I have to implement it myselft so Collections.Generic.SortedList<T> would not be a good option for me.... is there any algorithm available for that?

Comment: Here is the MSDN library documentation on Self Balancing BSTs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms379573(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a great many algorithms for self-balancing search trees, many of which are complex and others of which are quite straightforward (albeit, with some caveats).

The book "Introduction to Algorithms, Second Edition" by Cormen, Leisserson, Rivest, and Stein is an excellent introduction to algorithms and covers [red/black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) very well.  It's also a great book in general on algorithms and data structures.

If you're interested in using [splay trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree), which are extremely fast and actually quite easy to implement, the [original paper on the data structure](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/self-adjusting.pdf) is very accessible.  On top of that, it includes a proof of all the runtime bounds.

The [treap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap) is a simple randomized balanced binary search tree that can be implemented quite easily once you know how to implement [tree rotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation).  Tree rotations are also used in splay trees as well, and so it might be worth investigating.

For [AVL trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree), [this lecture](http://www.cs.kent.edu/~javed/class-ALG00S/webbook/ALG00S-L10b.pdf) seems to be a good resource.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

check out http://code.google.com/p/self-balancing-avl-tree/ , implements a self balancing avl tree in c#. plus it also implements concatenate and split operations.